# Wrapping `tr` tag with `Link` gives Hydration Error in Next.js 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next.js14

I'm using `next.js 14`. I want to wrap all of my `<tr>` tags in `<Link>`. But doing so gives me `Hydration error`.

I could do something like `onclick={() => doThing()}` but in that case, I have to make my component client side. (which I hardly want to)

Here's a minimal reproduceable code:

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <Link href="#">
          <tr>
            <th>John</th>
            <td>Williums</td>
          </tr>
        </Link>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Error I get:
[image: Hydration Error]

Comment: "*I want to wrap...my tr tags in Link*" - I can't offer insight regarding the framework and tools, but I'll point out that you're trying to create invalid HTML. The *only* valid parents for a [`<tr>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) are [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead), [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody), and [`<tfoot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tfoot).

Comment: @DavidThomas I understand, but my purpose was - each of the `th` represents a user in a leaderboard. So, when someone clicks on it, it brings them to the user's profile page. 
Now I went to flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make another component for table and name it Table
then in Home component you have to import this component dyanmic and ssr false like this example:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const Table = dynamic(() => import('./table'), { ssr: false })
export default function Home() {
  return (
      <Table />
   );
}
```

Comment: This solves the hydration problem, but still I get `validateDOMNesting` Warning as this is an invalid HTML as @DavidThomas had pointed out